# Where should i edit to draw two triangles in webGL (with html, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

This below is my code.
I want to show two triangles, but it always only show just one triangle.
Where should i edit and how to edit..? (can you tell me like axx (x) -> ayy (o) ? )

I have already tried about it more than 4 or 5 hours... but result is disappointing to me.
Please tell me where should i edit...

```
var gl;
var points;

window.onload = function init()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }


    //var vertices = new Float32Array([vec2(-1, -1), vec2(-0.5, 1), vec2(0, -1), [vec2(0, -1), vec2(0.5, 1), vec2(1, -1)]);
    var vertices = [ vec2(-1.0,-1.0), vec2(-0.5,1.0), vec2(0.0,-1.0), vec2(0.0, -1.0), vec2(0.5, 1.0), vec2(1.0, -1.0)];
    // var vertices_02 = [ vec2(0.0, -1.0), vec2(0.5, 1.0), vec2(1.0, -1.0)];
    //  Configure WebGL

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers

    var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );

    // Load the data into the GPU

    var bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW );


    // Associate vertex data buffer with shader variables

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    render();
};


function render() {
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6 );
}
```

Comment: I recommend learning about how OpenGL rendering pipeline works. You can find fundamentals in this article https://dev.opera.com/articles/introduction-to-webgl-part-1/

Comment: You haven't posted enough code to tell what is wrong. At a glance [nothing is wrong with the code you posted](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/z05btLgq/). I'd strongly suggest you read [these articles](https://webglfundamentals.org) if you want to learn WebGL. The ones you're reading have poor choices IMO. Also the one linked by @blami is 9 years out of date and uses a discontinued library

Comment: @gman thanks for clarification and up to date link. I posted article mainly to explain how pipeline works.